# Binding to a knockout computed function that returns an array of objects

Tags: arrays, knockout.js

I have the following code:

```
self.usedTables = ko.computed(function () {
    var usedTables = []; // doesn't need to be observable, just array

    if (self.selectedJoins() != null) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedJoins(), function (j) {
            if (j.firstTable() != '' && ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(usedTables, j.firstTable()) == -1) {
                usedTables.push(j.firstTable());
            }
            if (j.secondTable() != '' && ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(usedTables, j.secondTable()) == -1) {
                usedTables.push(j.secondTable());
            }
        });
    }

    return usedTables;
});
```

Both firstTable and secondTable return objects with the following pattern:

```
var tableRecord = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.tableName = ko.observable();
    self.fields = ko.observableArray([]);
};
```

In other places in this project, when I've needed to bind an ko.observableArray to a select, I was able to do so using data-bind = "options: allTables, optionsText: tableName".  This works even if the array is empty.  However, when I attempt to bind the results of the above code in a similar manner, I get an error if the array returns an empty set:

"JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'tableName' of undefined or null reference".

How do I bind this to a select?

Per request, adding code that loads allTables

```
self.seedTables = function () {
        var regis = new tableRecord();
        regis.tableName('regis');
        regis.fields.push(new fieldClass('internal_id', 'string'));
        regis.fields.push(new fieldClass('exam', 'string'));
        regis.fields.push(new fieldClass('admin_date', 'date'));
        regis.fields.push(new fieldClass('pass_fail', 'string'));

        self.allTables.push(regis);

        var ei = new tableRecord();
        ei.tableName('exam_info');

        ei.fields.push(new fieldClass('exam', 'string'));
        ei.fields.push(new fieldClass('name', 'string'));
        ei.fields.push(new fieldClass('exam_type', 'string'));
        ei.fields.push(new fieldClass('type', 'string'));
        ei.fields.push(new fieldClass('admin_date', 'date'));

        self.allTables.push(ei);
    ...
```

Comment: try binding the same by checking data-bind="ifnot: allTables().length == 0" and also a null condition and then bind it to the select tag. also make sure you have elements in allTables. And can you post the code where you are using allTables and pushing values to it?

Comment: added the code as requested. Possibly it works because allTables is a ko.obserableArray, not a function returning an array. I'll play around with your suggestion, look into conditional binding ... thanks.

Comment: I guess everything in javascript is a function Steve..  Anywayz... is your issue solved? Let me know if still you are facing issue or if my suggestion didnt exactly help you